# Gulp. Конкатенация одного-единственного файла к некоторому их числу

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, gulp, less

Возможно чего-то не понял( скорее всего, так и есть), но так и не удалось выполнить следующую задачу:

Есть каталог **/src/js** 
В нём( безо всяких вложенных каталогов) лежат .js файлы, соответствующие разным страницам. Название каждого из них начинается с названия страницы( т.е для одного-единственного скрипта страницы *services.php*, будет скрипт *services.js*)
Практически все эти скрипты используют jQuery. 
Поэтому, для наведения порядка в итоговой версии, потребовалось добавить один файл( **jquery.min.js** ) в начало каждого файла из входного потока( *./src/js/*.js* ). Сделать этого не удалось. Собсно, каким образом это( добавить произвольный файл или неск в начало каждого выходного) можно реализовать НЕ прибегая к описанию *руками* адреса каждого исходного файла и целой горы неведомых трюков, с этим связанных?

П.С: несколько аналогичный вопрос и по CSS:
Есть конторный, специальным образом подготовленный( убран ненужный хлам итд) *bootstrap.min.css* 
Проект делается с применением LESS ( фу, ну да ладно). 
Т.е вначале все нужные .less файлы компилятся, потом - минифицируются, на выходе давая *конфетку*.

Проблема в том, что css файл подрубить в LESS не так уж и просто: 
a. если подключать его как css ( **@import (css) "адрес";**), тогда в итоговом файле CSS будет просто ссылка на него( т.е припишется CSS-ный импорт соотв. файла)
b. если подключать его как less ( **@import (less) "блаблабла";**), тогда начинают сыпаться ошибки, т.к это, мало того, что не LESS, так ещё и минимизированный. Была идея всё это *экранировать*, заключив всё содержимое переименованного в *bootstrap.min.less* в **~"css-код, который никак не проверяется препроцессором, а сразу выплёвывается в выходной файл"**, однако, это не удалось, ввиду обилия в упомянутом как одинарных, так и двойных кавычек.

Засим, аналогичный вопрос: каким образом к каждому из получаемых css файлов( на одну страницу получается один css файл за исключением бутстраповского), в начало поместить содержимое некоторого файла( *bootstrap.min.css*) ?

Comment: Вы не задумывались все файлы совместить в один и поключать на всех страницах, кэширование в браузерах никто не отменял ...

Comment: На самом деле, вам не нужно ничего ни с чем склеивать. Достаточно всего лишь подключать jquery отдельным тегом `<script ... >` чуть выше ваших скриптов на тех страницах, где это действительно необходимо. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать -- чудовищный костыль.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, В настоящий момент оно так и делается: подключается по 2 js и CSS файла( **jquery.min.js** и **всё_для_текущей_страницы_в_одном.min.js**, а также, **bootstrap.min.js** и **всё_для_текущей_страницы_в_одном.min.css**).


Кстати, чего костылёвого в попытке слить все скрипты для текущей страницы воедино ? 
-Т.к, это в данном случае лишь один-единственный jquery, а в иной раз, сторонних скриптов с десяток-другой ( притом, для каждой из страниц - по разному), что превращается в какую-то ужасную свалку :(

Однако, момент с чудовищным костылём, учту

Comment: @AlEX костыль в сливании **всех** библиотек (даже неиспользуемых) в один скрипт. Это приводит к ситуации, когда вы для каждой страницы загружаете огромную пачку JS кода, а кеширование на уровне HTTP работает только постранично, т.е. нельзя закешировать только jQuery. Вообще, есть удобные средства (вроде browserify), которые позволяют сливать только те скрипты, которые действительно нужны. Однако в этом случае, вам скорее всего придется адаптировать весь ваш JS код.

Comment: @AlEX сейчас подготовлю развернутый ответ)

Answer (score 1):

**Небольшое лирическое отступление**

Подход с объединением всех *необходимых* JS библиотек в один файл вместе с использующими их скриптами имеет как плюсы так и минусы.

Плюсы объединения:

- Вам не нужно писать портянку тэгов `<script>` в HTML коде страниц.
- Вам не нужно беспокоиться, что какая-то библиотека обновилась/добавилась/удалилась а вы забыли изменить/добавить/удалить соответствующий тэг `<script>`.
- Браузеры имеют ограничения на количество одновременно открываемых соединений. Поэтому, если у вас действительно много библиотек, то загружать один большой файл может быть эффективнее, чем очень много маленьких. Это связано с накладными расходами на открытие/переиспользование соединений.

Минусы такого подхода вполне очевидны:

- Вы не можете использовать кэширование отдельных библиотек на уровне HTTP запросов.
- Вы не можете использовать CDN для загрузки сторонних библиотек.
- Вам нужен некий слой сборки, который будет заниматься "склеиванием" библиотек.
- Вам нужно помнить, что при добавлении зависимости в ваш JS код вам нужно будет править сборочные скрипты (конечно, если вы не используете [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) или аналоги).

В целом, в склеивании библиотек нет ничего страшного, но только если вы склеиваете **необходимые** для конкретной страницы библиотеки, а не все сразу.

Для решения подобной задачи очень часто используются инструменты, вроде [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) (который, кстати, неплохо интегрируется с Gulp). Подобные инструменты умеют анализировать ваш код, и генерируют сборку, включающую только необходимые для ее работы библиотеки и модули. Проблема только в том, что для использования Browserify вам скорее всего придется изменить свой подход к написанию JavaScript кода.

---

**Теперь о вашей конкретной проблеме**

В экосистеме gulp есть большое количество всевозможных плагинов. Одним из таких плагинов является [gulp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header). Этот плагин позволяет вставить произвольное содержимое в начало каждого файла в потоке. А использовать этот плагин можно, например, так:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    header = require('gulp-header');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/*.js')
        .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('./libs/jquery.js') + "\n"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Как то так ...

```
gulp.task('build', function() {

    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readdir('/src/', function(err, items) {

        console.log(items);

        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            if(/^(.*)\.js$/.test(items[i])) {
               gulp.src(['jquery.min.js', items[i]])... и т.д.
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Но по моему вариант с раздельной склейкой не лучший вариант ...

Comment: Не будет нормально работать в комбинации с другими "тасками" gulp. Вы не используете функцию обратного (как впрочем и другие средства) для индикации того, что "таск" `default` завершен.

Comment: @dmitriy-simushev, где вы у меня усмотрели "таск" `default` ?

Comment: Прошу прощения, имел в виду `build`. Все остальное из комментария выше справедливо.